# Determine the enlargement factor of an image automatically to scale it back down

Tags: workflow, image-quality, image-editing, bitmap

This might be hard to explain.

If I have an image that was obviously enlarged (i.e. pixels are visible), can I revert the enlargement process to get the original picture back?

For example this image:

[image]

It's obvious that it was enlarged because of the visible pixels on the curves of the letters.

I thought I could do this by measuring the pixels on the enlarged image, but some are 5 x 5 and some are 6 x 5...

[image]

### Can an app easily determine the enlargement factor based on neighboring identical pixels? This would make reverting the enlargement very easy.

Comment: I'm gonna say no. I doubt there is an application that would bother to try doing that. Maybe someone somewhere has tried it just for fun, but it doesn't even make much sense in my opinion. _Even if_ you managed to guess correctly, enlarging adds pixels and downsizing removes pixels so it's not going to look as good as the original. The easier and better way to handle this is to always have access to the original.

Comment: @Joonas Good answer - you should post it below.

Comment: The question states that don't "have the original". If the original was accessible, this question wouldn't have a reason to exist.

Comment: @MicroMachine even so. What would be the benefit of automatically detecting teh enlargement factor when you can do abuest guess yourself easily. Anyway not all or even most enlargement is done with nearest neghbour

Comment: @MicroMachine, I know, it was more of a vague suggestion for the future. People don't tend to upsize an image destroying the quality and then overwrite the original with that, then close everything and come back later like "whoopsie". I mean accidents happen, but even then more often than not there is a way to roll back the original. For working in Photoshop I would suggest overwriting files with caution and using Smart Objects to avoid destroying originals as they are placed in the document.

Comment: My question was simply whether there is a machine or AI way of detecting the enlargement factor of an image, by identifying identical neighboring pixels. Not really whether or not there are workflows that are better to avoid errors. Obviously a lot of people today work with files they didn't create, if they work in large teams or inherited data from someone who passed, etc.

Comment: Drop any client that dumps your upsized files like this one the regular. Like who in their right mind does that? Save image without upsizing it first. It's not so hard.

Comment: Ehm... 99% of people in the world do not know how to use a computer correctly. And a lot of apps exist whose purpose *is* to screw up images real well (batch actions in PS to upscale? Yea it can be done...). That's why designers have jobs... To fix the wrongs of this world for a fee. Feel free to send me your rejected clients :D

Comment: And here he is asking for an automated software. Hah :D

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. Someone gave a perfectly fine answer while it just seems you're criticizing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of the squares are 5x5.  So the best you can do is to rescale to 1/5th the size on each dimension.

The width is 1348px. Divide by 5 and you get 270px (rounding to the nearest whole pixel).

In Photoshop, do *Image > Image Size* or in GIMP do *Image > Scale Image*, then type in the new width. You may need to experiment with the resampling/interpolation methods for the best result. It will never be a perfect reversal of the scaling however, since the image will have to be resampled.